# Vue virtual DOM not updating immediately when followed by expensive calculation

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js

I'm trying to add a loading screen that displays while my app is doing expensive hashing and deciphering of some data (takes 2-3 seconds). When I experimentally remove the expensive parts following what should update the DOM, the screen loads immediately. Otherwise, it doesn't render until after the expensive function is complete. Any ideas what I'm screwing up?

```js
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      loading: false,
      password: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async unlock(){
      this.loading = true;
      await this.$nextTick()
      // DOM should update, but it doesn't
      try{
        await this.$root.UnlockVaultPassword(this.password);
      } catch(err){
        this.loading = false;
        return;
      }
      // DOM updates once finished with hashing and ciphering
      this.loading = false;
      this.$router.push({name: 'vault'});
    }
  }
}
```

I'm thinking that because vue updates the dom asynchronously, I'm experiencing a race condition where it can't fit in the dom update amidst the hashing. How can I WAIT until the dom is done?

Comment: Setting `this.loading = true` alone does trigger a rerender?

Comment: correct. It definitely has something to do with the computational expensiveness.

Comment: How about trying this.$forceUpdate() to force vue to update DOM.

Comment: Caveat with `$forceUpdate`: it will not re-render all child elements.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, doesn't work. The render is getting triggered, but for some reason the hashing is interfering

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using the `mounted` hook? And call the `unlock` function as a separate operation after `$nextTick` for good separation of concerns.

```
  mounted () {
    this.loading = true;

    this.$nextTick(function () {
      this.unlock();
    })
  }

  methods: {
    unlock: function() {
      // unlock code
      this.loading = false;
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE**: try having a handler function that first sets `loading` on form submission, then defers to `unlock` as the callback to `$nextTick`, like so:

```
  methods: {
    handleFormSubmit: function() {
      this.loading = true;
      this.$nextTick(this.unlock);
    },
    unlock: function() {
      // unlock code
      this.loading = false;
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE 2**: if none of the above works, it's starting to sound like a bug in the expected behavior of `$nextTick`, in that rendering is not completed before executing the following code. What happens if you use a `setTimeout` to force the unlock processes to the end of the execution stack?

```
  methods: {
    handleFormSubmit: function() {
      this.loading = true;
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        setTimeout(this.unlock, 0);
      });
    },
    unlock: function() {
      // unlock code
      this.loading = false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the "unlock" function is triggered on a form submit

Comment: Ah. But what about passing `unlock` in the callback to `$nextTick`? Let me modify my example.

Comment: My thinking is there's maybe a race condition where `$nextTick` executes, but the DOM hasn't fully re-rendered by the time `UnlockVaultPassword` is called. Seems odd because your code *looks* right.

Comment: Another suggestion: offloading the complex hashing/deciphering to an async process, either on the backend or perhaps [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API). Might have performance benefits anyway, if your deciphering code is locking up the single threaded JS processes for 2-3 seconds.

Comment: Same effect unfortunately, and I can't unload to backend because the app doesn't rely on a backend (electron)

Comment: This almost sounds like a bug in `$nextTick`! See my UPDATE 2, maybe try using `setTimeout` to force execution of the unlock code to the end of the JS call stack?

Comment: @benjarwar pretty wild that nextTick + setTimeout hack worked for something I'm working on. feels dirty, but works.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a workaround... I don't love it but it isn't too horrible. I can actually push the callback onto the event loop so that my hashing will only happen after rendering is complete.

```js
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      loading: false,
      password: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async unlock(){
      this.loading = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        try{
          await this.$root.UnlockVaultPassword(this.password);
        } catch(err){
          this.loading = false;
          return;
        }
        this.loading = false;
        this.$router.push({name: 'vault'});
      }, 0)
    }
  }
}
```